# SAGAN - what is the correct architecture?

Tags: gan, attention-mechanism, deep-learning, adversarial-ml

Hi, in the original paper the following scheme of the self-attention appears:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08318.pdf
[image]

In a later overview:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01529.pdf

this scheme appears:
[image]
referring the original paper.

My understanding more correlates with the second paper scheme, as:
[image]
Where there is two dot-product operations and three hidden parametric matrices:
$$W_k, W_v, W_q$$
which corresponds to $W_f, W_g, W_h$ without $W_v$ as it in the original paper explanation, which is as following:

[image]

Is this a mistake in the original paper ?